# C dynamically allocating struct, seg fault when using scanf

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Person {
  char* name;
  int age;
};

void printit(struct Person *person) {
    printf("%s %d \n",person->name,person->age);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  struct Person *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
  printf("Enter name: ");
  scanf("%s", p->name);
  printf("Enter age: ");
  scanf("%d", &(p->age));
  printit(p);
  free(p);
}
```

Enter name: asdf

Segmentation fault: 11

I don't know why it is giving segmentation fault....

Comment: `char* name;` --> `char name[64];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You allocated memory for the `struct`.

But you did not allocate memory where `p->name` would point to

---

Add this to your code.

```
struct Person *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
p->name = malloc(100);
```

---

**EDIT**

No type should be explicitly allocated space inside a struct.

When you did

```
struct Person *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

space gets allocated for `name` and `age` both. But notice that `name` is a pointer variable. Space has been allocated for the pointer variable, but not where the pointer will point to.

It is like when you do

```
char* p;
```

The variable `p` is created, space is allocated for it, but if you want to use it, you have two options.

1) Either make it point to some existing allocated memory

```
char* p;
char arr[10];
p = arr;
```

2) Or allocate memory where it will point at.

```
char* p = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working now! May I ask what types should be explicitly allocated in a struct besides char*?

Comment: It makes sense! Thanks so much!